# TravisCI did not run after adding more configuration to .travis.yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github, travis-ci

I added some AWS keys to my `.travis.yml` file so that it would deploy my application over to ElasticBeanstalk, but after I committed the changes to the file and pushed to master, nothing happened.

I thought perhaps I needed to restart build. This added my AWS keys, but no installation of deployment dependencies as I had expected and no deployment to AWS.

Not sure what happened here. Did I not wait long enough for TravisCI to start the new build?

This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t danale/project-name -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run danale/project-name npm run test -- --coverage

  deploy:
    provider: elasticbeanstalk
    region: "us-east-1"
    app: "project-name"
    env: "ProjectName-env"
    bucket_name: "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-123456789"
    bucket_path: "project-name"
    on:
      branch: master
    access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
    secret_access_key: 
      secure: "$AWS_SECRET_KEY"
```

I conducted a `git add . && git commit -m "added travis deploy script" && git push origin master`

No deployment afterwards. I don't see where I missed a step here:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the headaches of `.yml` files is the indentation. So the parse error I was getting in the Request tab was saying no newline added. I was not clear whether that meant it needed a new line or was missing a new line, but by running: `wc -l .travis.yml` I was able to detect that it was not outputting the correct number of lines.

I tried about five different ways to format the `.yml` file allowing it to keep me focused towards the end of the files line number where the error was pointing towards.

I happen to look up and realized the beginning of the deploy: script was not properly aligned, so I adjusted with a shift+tab and after I got it properly aligned, TravisCI recognized my changes and properly ran the script and successfully deployed the application to Elasticbeanstalk.

Comment: Try adding `yamllint` to your git workflow, so before committing an unparsable yaml file you can validate it. I end up adding this to my git-hook scripts.

Comment: @Hashfyre, thank you for the tip. I am going to look into that today.